# trigger.io | Styling the status bar (where appear carrier signal)

Tags: trigger.io

I develop an app with trigger.io for iOS 7.

My application is "dark" style.

By default, the status bar remain white/gray. (the status bar i talk about is the apple bar where appear carrier name, time, etc..)

I want this bar to be with a black background and white text. (or anything like that, but nice with a dark application).

I am afraid i can't customize this (it would be a very bad news for me).

I tried to modify the Info.plist with

key:UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance
bool value : false

key : UIStatusBarStyle
value : UIStatusBarStyleLightContent

but it seem to corrupt my generated ipa.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest version of the [display module](https://trigger.io/modules/display/current/), your app should fill the whole screen on iOS7. This also includes the part behind the status bar. You can therefore change the background color of the top 20px of your app to the color of your choice, in this case black.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's ok for the status bar.

Comment: But in fact, i have a problem... I can't choose the text color of the text in the status bar. Carrier name and signal is black. And my app is dark...
Any idea to switch the text to white ?

Comment: You may want to try to use an invisible forge.topbar for that. Just activate the topbar module in your config and call this early on in the app: `forge.topbar.hide();` `forge.topbar.setStatusBarStyle('light_content');`